# Setting height and width to TileWMS layer in OpenLayers 3

Tags: geoserver, wms, openlayers, geowebcache

I'm trying to set up a TileWMS layer in OpenLayers 3 as:

```
var baseMap = new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: "MayBase Map",
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: mapUrl,
        params: {
            'LAYERS': 'GIS_Demo', 
            'TILED':     true,
            'SRS':'EPSG:900913',
            'WIDTH':256,
            'HEIGHT':256},
        serverType: 'geoserver'
     })
 });
```

But when I actually request I get the URL like:

`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=GIS_Demo&TILED=true&SRS=EPSG:900913&WIDTH=205&HEIGHT=205&CRS=EPSG:3857&STYLES=&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:81&BBOX=8624542.775473006,1452915.0336446315,8629434.745283257,1457807.003454883`

Here even though I am setting the height and width of 256 each its somehow overriding the default values of 205 (for more view [docs](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.source.TileWMS.html)).

This is basically causing the **GWC error** as : `400: The requested tile dimensions 205x205 do not match those of the grid set (256x256)`

Why is this happening? is this a bug? or is there any other way of specifying the width and height?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had similar problem, adding

```
 pixelRatio: 1,
```

to ol.Map section solved the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/jLmyo3gL/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.source.TileWMS.html documentation carefully, at the end of the params option it says

> WIDTH, HEIGHT, BBOX and CRS (SRS for WMS version < 1.3.0) **will be set dynamically**.

To change your tile dimensions you need to set the a [tilegrid](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.tilegrid.TileGrid.html) to the tilegrid option, but 256x256 is the default so you can just leave that option out.

```
var baseMap = new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: "MayBase Map",
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: mapUrl,
        params: {'LAYERS': 'GIS_Demo', 'TILED': true,'SRS':'EPSG:900913'},
        serverType: 'geoserver'
      })
  });
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, but i have tried what u suggested by default. And with it the request as usual takes 205x205 as tile size. That's the reason why i have provided the explicit option for tile size which is unfortunately not working.

Comment: @Suraj are you able to put your code up on a http://jsfiddle.net?  You can hit the Create JSFiddle button from http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/examples/wms-tiled.html?q=TileWMS as a starting point

Comment: I have also same problem,here i am giving code https://jsfiddle.net/seema30/gtmq47sq/1/  please help me.